Powershell program, displaying function not working [SOLVED]
Morning to everyone,
I have an issue with a powershell script.
Context
I'm trying to create a program to edit tf2 pop file in powershell, right now I'm trying to have a program that open a txt file, display the content of every wavespawn and a button to copy the wavespawn.
Here the powershell script I currently wrote with a bit of help.
# Import necessary assemblies for Windows Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Function to create OpenFileDialog
function Show-OpenFileDialog {
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
    $openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $openFileDialog.Title = "Select a Text File"
    $result = $openFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $openFileDialog.FileName
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}

# Function to load file content and extract WaveSpawn sections
function Load-FileContent {
    param (
        [string]$filePath,
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]$listBox,
        [ref]$waveSpawnDetails
    )
    $listBox.Items.Clear()
    $waveSpawnDetails.Value.Clear()
    if (Test-Path $filePath) {
        $content = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
        # Extract all WaveSpawn sections with a more robust regex pattern
        $waveSpawns = [regex]::Matches($content, 'WaveSpawn\s*\{(?:[^\{\}]*|(?<Open>\{)|(?<-Open>\}))*\}(?(Open)(?!))')
        $waveSpawns | ForEach-Object {
            $waveSpawn = $_.Value
            if ($waveSpawn -match 'Name\s+(\w+)') {
                $name = $matches[1]
                $listBox.Items.Add($name)
                $waveSpawnDetails.Value[$name] = $waveSpawn
            }
        }
    } else {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("File not found: $filePath", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    }
}

# Function to display details of the selected WaveSpawn
function Show-WaveSpawnDetails {
    param (
        [string]$waveSpawnName,
        [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]$textBox,
        [hashtable]$waveSpawnDetails
    )
    if ($waveSpawnDetails.ContainsKey($waveSpawnName)) {
        $textBox.Text = $waveSpawnDetails[$waveSpawnName]
    } else {
        $textBox.Text = "WaveSpawn details not found."
    }
}

# Main form
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "WaveSpawns"
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(800, 600)

# ListBox to display WaveSpawns
$listBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(300, 500)
$listBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 10)

# TextBox to display selected WaveSpawn details
$textBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(450, 500)
$textBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(320, 10)
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = [System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars]::Vertical

# Button to copy WaveSpawn details to clipboard
$copyButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$copyButton.Text = "Copy"
$copyButton.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$copyButton.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(320, 520)
$copyButton.Add_Click({
    Set-Clipboard -Value $textBox.Text
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("WaveSpawn copied to clipboard!")
})

# Button to open file
$openButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$openButton.Text = "Open File"
$openButton.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$openButton.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 520)
$openButton.Add_Click({
    $filePath = Show-OpenFileDialog
    if ($filePath) {
        Load-FileContent -filePath $filePath -listBox $listBox -waveSpawnDetails ([ref]$waveSpawnDetails)
    }
})

# Add event handler for ListBox selection
$listBox.SelectedIndexChanged.Add({
    $selectedWaveSpawnName = $listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Show-WaveSpawnDetails -waveSpawnName $selectedWaveSpawnName -textBox $textBox -waveSpawnDetails $waveSpawnDetails
})

# Add controls to form
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Controls.Add($copyButton)
$form.Controls.Add($openButton)

# Initialize hashtable to store WaveSpawn details
$global:waveSpawnDetails = @{}

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()

The test "pop" file
//This mission is a dummy mission and is probably not working, it just here to test the powershell script in "real condition"

#base robot_standard.pop
#base robot_giant.pop


WaveSchedule
{
    StartingCurrency 900
    RespawnWaveTime 4
    CanBotsAttackWhileInSpawnRoom no
    
    Mission
    {
        Objective   DestroySentries
        BeginAtWave 1
        RunForThisManyWaves 3
        InitialCooldown 30
        CooldownTime    30
        DesiredCount    1
        Where   spawnbot_mission_sentrybuster
        
        TFBot
        {
            Template    T_TFBot_SentryBuster
        }
    }   
    
    Wave    //wave 1    
    {

        StartWaveOutput
        {
            Target  wave_start_relay
            Action  Trigger
        }
        DoneOutput
        {
            Target  wave_finished_relay
            Action  Trigger
        }
        
        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave1
            TotalCurrency   300
            TotalCount  4
            MaxActive   6
            SpawnCount  1
            WaitBeforeStarting  0
            WaitBetweenSpawns   12
            Where   spawnbot

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Pyro
                Tag bot_giant
                Attributes  AlwaysFireWeapon
            }   
        }
        
        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave1
            TotalCurrency   100
            TotalCount  24
            MaxActive   12
            SpawnCount  2
            WaitBeforeStarting  2
            WaitBetweenSpawns   2.5
            Where   spawnbot_side
            
            Squad
            {
                TFBot
                {
                
                    Class Soldier
                    Skill normal
                }           
                TFBot
                {
                    Template    T_TFBot_Medic_QuickFix
                    Tag bot_squad_member
                    
                    ItemAttributes
                    {
                        ItemName "The Quick-Fix"
                        "ubercharge rate bonus" 0.1
                    }
                }
            }   
        }   
        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave2
            WaitForAllSpawned w1a
            TotalCurrency   100
            TotalCount  3
            MaxActive   3
            SpawnCount  1
            WaitBeforeStarting  7
            WaitBetweenSpawns   7
            Where   spawnbot

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Demoman
                Tag bot_giant
            }   
        }

        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave2
            WaitForAllSpawned w1a
            TotalCurrency   300
            TotalCount  1
            MaxActive   1
            SpawnCount  1
            WaitBeforeStarting  2
            WaitBetweenSpawns   1

            FirstSpawnOutput
            {
                Target boss_spawn_relay
                Action Trigger
            }
            
            Tank
            {
                Name "Tank"
                Health 15000
                Speed 70
                StartingPathTrackNode tank_path_1
                OnKilledOutput
                {
                    Target boss_dead_relay
                    Action Trigger
                }
                OnBombDroppedOutput
                {
                    Target boss_deploy_relay
                    Action Trigger
                }
            }
        }
        
        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave3
            WaitForAllSpawned w1b
            TotalCurrency   50
            TotalCount  2
            MaxActive   2
            SpawnCount  1
            WaitBeforeStarting  4
            WaitBetweenSpawns   7
            Where   spawnbot_side

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Scout_FAN
                Tag bot_giant
            }   
        }       
        
        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave3
            WaitForAllSpawned w1b
            Support 1
            TotalCurrency   50
            TotalCount  50
            MaxActive   10
            Support Limited
            SpawnCount  5
            WaitBeforeStarting  7
            WaitBetweenSpawns   1
            Where   spawnbot_invasion

            TFBot
            {
                Class Demoman
            }   
        }
    }           
}   

And the result
Also here the error message when I try to copy a wavespawn
This is the only error I'm getting.
mpossible d’appeler une méthode dans une expression Null.
Au caractère P:\Document\Fichier texte\Switch_supervision - Copie.ps1:99 : 1
+ $listBox.SelectedIndexChanged.Add({
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Can anyone help me figure it out what is happening with the script and why two of the main function doesn't work ?
UPDATE: The solution has been found by @Someone if anyone is interested here the working code:
# Import necessary assemblies for Windows Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Function to create OpenFileDialog
function Show-OpenFileDialog {
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
    $openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $openFileDialog.Title = "Select a Text File"
    $result = $openFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $openFileDialog.FileName
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}

# Function to load file content and extract WaveSpawn sections
function Load-FileContent {
    param (
        [string]$filePath,
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]$listBox,
        [ref]$waveSpawnDetails
    )
    $listBox.Items.Clear()
    $waveSpawnDetails.Value.Clear()
    if (Test-Path $filePath) {
        $content = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
        # Extract all WaveSpawn sections with a more robust regex pattern
        $waveSpawns = [regex]::Matches($content, 'WaveSpawn\s*\{(?:[^\{\}]*|(?<Open>\{)|(?<-Open>\}))*\}(?(Open)(?!))')
        $waveSpawns | ForEach-Object {
            $waveSpawn = $_.Value
            if ($waveSpawn -match 'Name\s+(\w+)') {
                $name = $matches[1]
                $listBox.Items.Add($name)
                $waveSpawnDetails.Value[$name] = $waveSpawn
            }
        }
    } else {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("File not found: $filePath", "Error", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    }
}

# Function to display details of the selected WaveSpawn
function Show-WaveSpawnDetails {
    param (
        [string]$waveSpawnName,
        [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]$textBox,
        [hashtable]$waveSpawnDetails
    )
    if ($waveSpawnDetails.ContainsKey($waveSpawnName)) {
        $textBox.Text = $waveSpawnDetails[$waveSpawnName]
    } else {
        $textBox.Text = "WaveSpawn details not found."
    }
}

# Main form
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "WaveSpawns"
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(800, 600)

# ListBox to display WaveSpawns
$listBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(300, 500)
$listBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 10)

# TextBox to display selected WaveSpawn details
$textBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(450, 500)
$textBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(320, 10)
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = [System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars]::Vertical

# Button to copy WaveSpawn details to clipboard
$copyButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$copyButton.Text = "Copy"
$copyButton.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$copyButton.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(320, 520)
$copyButton.Add_Click({
    Set-Clipboard -Value $textBox.Text
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("WaveSpawn copied to clipboard!")
})

# Button to open file
$openButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$openButton.Text = "Open File"
$openButton.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$openButton.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 520)
$openButton.Add_Click({
    $filePath = Show-OpenFileDialog
    if ($filePath) {
        Load-FileContent -filePath $filePath -listBox $listBox -waveSpawnDetails ([ref]$waveSpawnDetails)
    }
})

# Add event handler for ListBox selection
$listBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $selectedWaveSpawnName = $listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Show-WaveSpawnDetails -waveSpawnName $selectedWaveSpawnName -textBox $textBox -waveSpawnDetails $waveSpawnDetails
})

# Add controls to form
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Controls.Add($copyButton)
$form.Controls.Add($openButton)

# Initialize hashtable to store WaveSpawn details
$global:waveSpawnDetails = @{}

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog() 


As the error indicates, there is a mistake in your line: $listBox.SelectedIndexChanged.Add({ The correct syntax to add an event to an object is: $listBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({

I am amazed how simple the error was. The program is now working as intended for now thank you for the solution
